# Alternative to LiveConnectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync for Windows Store app in C#

Tags: c#, onedrive

Couldn't figure out this but I believe it is due text vs. binary file.
How can I use LiveConnectClient.PutAsync to upload a binary file? 
LiveConnectClient.PutAsync(string, string) works fine for text files but when I try to upload a .zip file, it gets corrupted.
Anything to be done on the file content pass into PutAsync like encoding etc?

I do not wish to use BackgroundUploadAsync as it will create a phantom background task which can be seen in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out after repeatedly reading the API doc as I'm not familiar with HTML Post/Put/Get.
Code snippet below, just in case if anyone wanted something similar.

```
LiveConnectClient connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.Session);
Uri uri = new Uri("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + FolderID + "/files/" + Filename + "?access_token=" + connectClient.Session.AccessToken, UriKind.Absolute);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri);
request.Content = new HttpStreamContent(await InputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok)
{...}
```